# Android Bionic and Libc libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, libc, bionic

I want to create small command interpreter for android (shell). It should perform only few features : 'scanf','printf','cd', 'pwd', 'echo','set', 'unset', 'exit' and should support internal path variables : 'path', 'home', 'status'. 
Is it possible to fulfil this using Native Android Kit and bionic library. 
I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should just create an executable program binary with the NDK (e.g. use 'include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)' instead of 'include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)')